# Why can I not add an object to my arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, compiler-errors

The error message is:

```
StudentArray.java:14: error: constructor Student in class Student cannot be applied to given types;
      roster.add(new Student(name, id));
                 ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

It repeats this several times and also gives the Cannot Find Symbol error for my numberOfStudents variable. Here is the program, it's unfinished, but I can't move on without figuring this out. Thanks for your help!

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentArray {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      ArrayList<Student> roster = new ArrayList<>();
      int numberOfStudents = 0;

   }

   /** Add student method, includes student name and ID */
   public void addStudent(String name, String id) {
      roster.add(new Student(name, id));
      numberOfStudents++;
   }

   /** Overloaded addStudent method to include grades */
   public void addStudent(String name, String id, int grade1, int grade2, int grade3) {
      roster.add(new Student(name, id, grade1, grade2, grade3));
      numberOfStudents++;

   }

   /** Method to enter test grades */
   public void enterTestGrades(int testNumber) {
      int data = -1;
      for (int index : roster) {
         System.out.println("Enter the grade for " + roster.get(index) + ":");
         data = input.nextInt();
         roster.set(index, data);

      }
   }

   public void displayStudentInformation() {
   }

   public void displayMenu() {
   }
}
```

---

### Student class that the previous program is making an arraylist of, this one compiles fine.

```
/** Student Class */
public class Student2 {
   private String studentName;
   private String studentId;
   private final int NUMBER_OF_GRADES = 3;
   private int[] studentGrades = new int[NUMBER_OF_GRADES];
   private int averageGrade;
   private final int DEFAULT_GRADE = -1;

   /** No arg constructor */
   public Student2() {
      for (int index = 0; index < NUMBER_OF_GRADES; index++) {
         this.studentGrades[index] = DEFAULT_GRADE;
      }
   }

   /** Constructor that sets Student name and ID */
   public Student2(String name, String id) {
      this();
      this.studentName = name;
      this.studentId = id;
   }

   /** Constructor that sets all Student data */
   public Student2(String name, String id, int grade1, int grade2, int grade3) {
      this(name, id);
      this.studentGrades[0] = grade1;
      this.studentGrades[1] = grade2;
      this.studentGrades[2] = grade3;
   }

   /** Accessor for studentName */
   public String getStudentName() {
      return this.studentName;
   }

   /** Accessor for studentId */
   public String getStudentID() {
      return this.studentId;
   }

   /** Accessor for student grades */
   public int getStudentGrade(int index) {
      return this.studentGrades[index];
   }

   /** Return average student grade */
   public int getAverageStudentGrade() {
      int temp = 0;
      for (int index = 0; index < NUMBER_OF_GRADES; index++) { 
         temp += getStudentGrade(index);
      }

      int averageStudentGrade = temp / NUMBER_OF_GRADES;

      return averageStudentGrade;
   }

   /** Return letter grade */
   public char getLetterGrade(int grade) {

      int temp = grade / 10;
      char letterGrade;
      switch (temp) {
         case 10: 
         case 9: letterGrade = 'A';
                 break;
         case 8: letterGrade = 'B';
                 break;
         case 7: letterGrade = 'C';
                 break;
         case 6: letterGrade = 'D';
                 break;
         default: letterGrade = 'F';
                 break;
      }

      return letterGrade;
   }


   /** Setter method for studentName */
   public void setStudentName(String name) {
      this.studentName = name;
   }

   /** Setter method for studentId */
   public void setStudentId(String id) {
      this.studentId = id;
   }

   /** Setter for studentGrade */
   public void setStudentGrade(int grade, int index) {
      this.studentGrades[index] = grade;
   }
}
```

Thanks so much if you can help me. I'm totally stuck and this is my final project for my first java class.

Comment: Do you have 2 student classes ?

Comment: that's class `Student2` you pasted

Comment: oh, no. I remade it and saved the first edit as just Student.

Comment: `roster` is local variable of `main` class. You can't access it from outside. Something tells me that code you posted and error message are not related.

Comment: Oh, I see what I did, I named it Student2 and then tried to call just Student.

Comment: What @Pshemo said should be the answer, but just a quick suggestion, don't keep track of the number of students in a variable. You can get the number of students by returning the size of the ArrayList.

Comment: Well that fixed the constructor issue, I was just making a dumb mistake, but I'm very confused about what I've done wrong with the roster variable.

Comment: @JimboSakahana You are creating an ArrayList of Students named roster inside your main method and trying to access it outside of the main method. The variable is local to the main method and therefor can't be accessed outside the main method.

Comment: @yitzih "What Pshemo said should be the answer" if you mean that it should be also posted as answer then I have to disagree. Typographical errors are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Such questions should be closed instead of answered (we can help OP by writing hints in comments but posting answer will reduce Stack Overflow to debugging service rather than being repository of programming questions).

Answer (score 1):

The error message is actually pretty explicit: it fails to create an instance of Student because it cannot find any constructor that takes two Strings as arguments.

This means your class `Student` (not `Student2`) doesn't have this constructor.